# Python Function Return Type as Param to Another Script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-module

I have a script (module.py) with function definition (func). I am able to fetch the local variables (a) from another script (script.py) using import module and module.a utility.

But is there a way to retrieve the return type or local variables (b, n) within the function (func) and pass it to the calling script (script.py).

```
# Script Name: module.py
a = 10              # Module Script Local Variable
def func( n ):
    print(n + 20)
    b = 20          # Module Script Function Local Var.
    return n, b

print(a)             # Gives 10
print(n, b)          # NameError: name 'n'/'b' is not defined
```

Calling Script:

```
# Main Script Name: script.py
import module        # Or from module import a, func
a_new = module.a     # Gives 10
module.func(5)       # Function Call

n_new = module.n     # AttributeError: module 'module' has no attribute 'n'
b_new = module.b     # AttributeError: module 'module' has no attribute 'b'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `module.py` will execute the `print` calls once when imported. This is probably not what you want.

Regarding `n` and `b`: These are local to `module.func` and not available outside of this function.

Try this:

```
n_new, b_new = module.func(5)
```

Comment: ok. is there a way to print it in the module.py itself. The values of n and b?

Comment: Of course, but why? The idea of a module is to provide functions, classes, and methods for other code to use. A module usually is  not executed.

Comment: Marking it as the Correct Answer. Thanks.